# Is there a way to import the js library file to my DIH script?

Tags: solr, search-engine, solrnet, dataimporthandler, dih

I am importing some data using DIH, I'd like to use script transformer in order to perform some transformations before indexing.
As the transformations are a bit complex I am using an external js library.

My question is: Is there a way to import the js library file to my DIH script?

like:

```
<script src="lib/proj4js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Don't think there is an import feature. You can dump the contents of the js into the script tag and use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that there is no way to import js files into DIH data conf file.
Here is the answer I got from solr user's mailing list:

[solr-user-mailing-list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-solr-user/201212.mbox/browser)

It seems that, there is no where in script transformer code, where the script import is handled.

:(